# C# classes not printing out

Tags: c#

I’m trying to create a program which has multiple classes. In the program.cs I have inserted example text but whenever I run the program it doesn’t output the text it only outputs the name of the program and the class files, e.g. Testprogram.Customer

And I can’t workout why.

The Bank code is:

```cs
namespace CashMachine
{
    class Bank
    {
        private string bankname;
        private string location;

        public Bank(string name, string location)
        {
            this.bankname = bankname;
            this.location = location;
        }

        public string Getname()
        {
            return this.bankname;
        }

        public string Getlocation()
        {
            return this.location;
        }
    }
}
```

The program cs code is:

```cs
namespace CashMachine
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bank b = new Bank("NatWest", "London");
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine();
            Customer c = new Customer("Joe", "UK", "joelndn", "May");

            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you can't. But can I ask - how are you expecting us to help you work it out? Your question is a bit like asking a surgeon to perform the surgery on the patient's medical notes, instead of the patient. Where is your code? I struggle to comment on questions like this without sarcasm, because it genuinely baffles me as to how people imagine we are going to be able to fix their code without looking at it. There could be a dozen different reasons for your rather vague description of the problem, if not more. And also, as Will says, it's unclear what, if any, debugging you've tried already.

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: At a guess (because we can't see your code), you're doing something like `Console.WriteLine(myObject);`, where `myObject` doesn't have a `ToString()` overload, and so `ToString()` just returns the type name

Comment: (reopening because there should now be enough context to answer it)

Comment: Who will find the duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the first example, of `Bank`, you have:

```cs
Bank b = new Bank("NatWest", "London");
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Now; the system doesn't automatically know what you want to write about the `Bank`, but everything that subclasses `object` has a `public virtual string ToString()` method, **for creating a text representation of a type**, so: this is what gets called. The default implementation of `ToString()` is to output the type name, but if you want to do something more interesting: *tell it what you want*.

I would suggest:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return Getname();
}
```

You can do something similar with `Customer` to tell it what the default output would be for that.

Alternatively: just be explicit *in your output code*, i.e.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(b.Getname());
```

Finally, you might want to consider properties instead of methods like `Getname`, for example (using modern C# syntax):

```cs
class Bank
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Location { get; }
    public Bank(string name, string location)
    {
        Name = name;
        Location = location;
    }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Comment: Or just be more explicit in what you want to print/see e.g. Console.WriteLine(c.bankname);

Comment: Also, if explicitly for debug purposes, the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` is handy.

Comment: I don’t understand how to be more explicit because if I type console.writeline(b.bankname) it doesn’t work

Comment: @user10776032 - The suggestion didn't take into account that bankname is private. From your original code you'd use `c.Getname()` instead.